# How do I view the colorized output of Google Test in Xcode in the "All Output" window?

Tags: c++, xcode, unit-testing, googletest

I'm new to Xcode (and Macs in general) and am trying to port some of my code base over to run on both OS X and iOS.  I have a large set of unit tests written against the Google C++ Testing Framework (Google Test).  I successfully compiled the framework and I can run some tests, but I'm unsure how to view the colorized output from within Xcode.

I'm used to hitting "Run" in Visual Studio and immediately seeing a console window (with colors) letting me know at a glance if the tests passed or failed.

I've managed to set up a "Run Script" "Build Phase" but that seems to only output to the Log Navigator which obliterates the colors and even the fixed-width output making it very difficult to see at a glance if the tests pass.  I also can't find a way to display the log after running the tests.  When I do this nothing appears in the "All Output" window.

I've played around with XcodeColors but that doesn't seem to work with scripts that use the ANSI color codes.

At this point I wouldn't be surprised if this simply can't be done within Xcode.  That would be ideal, but if it isn't, is it possible to create a "Run Script" that will run the tests in an independent Terminal window?  Colors work fine there.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are links to a tool that colorizes the text in the Log window.  It's free and the source is in github so you can figure out how it works.  The first link says that it just uses simple ANSI codes to do the job.

http://deepitpro.com/en/articles/XcodeColors/info
https://github.com/robbiehanson/XcodeColors#readme

To kick off the execution from within Xcode, you will probably need to add a new target to your project.  To add a Target, click on your project and then there is an Add Target button on the bottom of the screen.  I don't know exactly what you're executing but here are my best guesses based on your question:

- MacOSX/Application/Cocoa-AppleScript or Command Line Tool - Create a simple script or program that will execute your units tests.
- MacOSX/Other/External Build System - Allows for execution of an external "make" program with args.

Once you have a way to execute your unit tests, you just need to figure out how to route the output from the unit tests to the Log window.  If you can edit the Google Test project and make it use `NSLog()`, that would seem to be the easiest solution.  You could create your own logging method, perform the ANSI colorization, and then send the final text to `NSLog()`.

**ADDED**: OK.  Interesting findings...  Read all before starting.  Here's what to do:

Start AppleScript Editor.  This is in LaunchPad.  Paste the following script into it:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "<your commands>" in window 1
end tell
```

You can repeat the "do script" line as needed.  Use this to execute your unit tests.  In Script Editor, do Save As.../File Format=Script and save it to a safe location for now like your Documents directory.  This will create a file like "UnitTests.scpt".

Now go to your iOS project.  Select the project at the top-left.  Select the Build Phases tab top-middle.  Click the Add Build Phase button on the bottom right.  Here's the interesting part.

Leave Shell as is ("/bin/sh").  Add one line:

```
osascript ~/Documents/UnitTests.scpt
```

That will execute the script after every build.

But here's the interesting part I found.  Click on Build Settings (top-middle).  Make sure All is selected (not Basic).  Scroll down the list to find Unit Testing.  Open Test Host.  Hit the + next to Debug.  You can also put the above `osascript` command here.  You might be able to execute your unit tests here and if you can, the output will likely show up in the Log!  Let me know what happens.

Comment: I'd really rather not have to edit the Google Test code.  That would imply that anything I want colorized would have to be rewritten to use `NSLog()` which, to me, is not feasible.  Google Test is already outputting in color presumably using ANSI codes since it shows up in color in Terminal and on Windows in the console.

I think I managed to route the output back into the output window (don't remember how unfortunately) but it wasn't in color.  I had hoped XcodeColors would help solve that problem but as you mentioned, I think it has to go through `NSLog()` :(

Comment: If you happen to know how to launch Terminal and run the tests (in color) when I hit "Run" the bounty is yours.

Comment: Working on it, but this bounty expires in 1 hour (or less).  This is approximately what the script will look like:  tell application Terminal/activate/do script "exec tests here"/end tell.

Comment: Well I'd really appreciate it if you can flesh that out but since you're the only soul to comment save matheszabi and the only one who responded to me, it's yours. :)

I'm new to OS X so even simple AppleScript baffles me at the moment.  Or at least coaxing it to execute from Xcode.

Comment: Thanks @Kent!  While I couldn't get anything to work under the Unit Testing settings, running the AppleScript does the job awesomely!

Comment: Glad to hear it.  I forgot to tell you that you can kick off the Unit Test command with Cmd-U or from menu Product/Test.

Answer (score 0):

I am familiar in Java: JUnit + JCodecoverage, at mobile applications: Android and iPhone I was to lazy to develop with TDD, but if I would like to start than :

I would create a Hello Word app, with JUnitTesting options turned on:
Include Unit Test checked

[image]

That will create a Test App / target whatever, and you will be able to run that.
The same thing it is at Android too: you have to create a "test project"
Once I did and forgot how is working, but, there are other stuff too:
- long press the Play button on Xcode ( 4.4 ) and you will have a dropdown menu with: Run, Test, Profile,Analyze.

I can't present those, because if I press the Shift+ Cmd + 4 to screenshot it it is changing, but here it look like the changed menu:
[image]

IMHO: for banking, forex, other financial or military (high security software) I would use test driven development, with over 99% code coverage, but those simple 3-4 web-service call mobile apps, which display public data available in browsers are just waste of time to develop tests and upkeep it!

Many times I need to test with internet connection and without.
to be worse case with WI-FI connection , but router doesn't give IP or let go out the phone, but if I ask the phone state: it is connected...

The GUI flow hard to test from unit testing, where is / would be usefully for me: the data got from web-service and synchronization with internal cache. As I see it is still cheaper to do it with manu testing.

Comment: Er, thanks for your time, but that really didn't answer my question.  I already have a large set of tests written against Google Test and this is a C++ project.